# Nginx SSL return nothing

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I am trying to use SSL to secure my Restful API which run behind nginx service.
I generated ssl certificate and keys from https://www.sslforfree.com and then copy pasted those keys into my server.
my nginx config file looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    server_name mysubdomain.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysubdomain_ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysubdomain_ssl/private_key.key;

    location /wwwroot/ {
        autoindex off;
        root /var/mysubdomain/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

my restful api application is running locally on my server on port 8001, I opened both ports 80 and port 443 on my firewall, I can successfully get response using http on my browser and postman http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/api/values but when I try with https I get this site can't be reached.
Here is the permission for the folder containing the certificate and key `drwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file `/etc/nginx/ssl/mysubdomain_ssl/certificate.crt` you need to add root and intermediate certificates of your CA. And then restart `nginx` server.
Check [this web page](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) from where you can get the missing certificates.

You need to combine the certificate and ca_bundle file in one file which to add as certificate

Comment: I got 3 files for sslfofree, certificate, ca_bundle and private key I copied them into 3 separate files with extension .crt for the first 2 files and .key for the 3rd one, which files should I use with nginx and how?

Comment: thanks so much for your answer also one thing to add in my nginx config is this line ```listen 443 ssl;```. you are the man